# Programmatically set UISlider to hidden

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uislider

I've added a UISlider to my scene in Xcode 5 ios7. In the attributes inspector there is a hidden property which prevents the screen element from showing.

What I'm trying to do is show/hide this element based on the touch up event of a button, however I'm having no luck. I've tried various methods such as:

```
self.percentagSlider.hidden = YES;
[self.percentagSlider setHidden:YES];
```

I've also tried options where I set the image of the slider to an [[UIimage alloc] init] (i.e. an empty image) with no success.

this is proving more tricky than it should be.

Comment: That code should work. Are you sure you have connected the slider to the `self.percentageSlider` IBOutlet property. What's the result of `NSLog(@"%@", self.percentageSlider);`?

Comment: thanks, just done a major scene refactor and it looks like a typo sneaked in there. Sorted

Comment: I think this question should be closed? serves no purpose...